# How to let the c++ output in the vc code terminal

Tags: c++, terminal, visual-studio-code

When I run a C++ program in vs code, it alway pops up a new window. Are there any ways to let the program output to the inner terminal (or output window) of vs code, instead of the annoying pop up window?

Comment: I want to ask how can you run program in a new window?

Comment: When I press F5 in vs code, a new window pop up with program result. It is just like coding in dev-cpp. And I want to the program output in the IED terminal, just like coding in eclipse.

Comment: Check your launch.json, change `externalConsole` to false.

Comment: When I did that, a new problem occured. **Unable to establish a connection to GDB**

Comment: Make sure you've set all the proper fields for debugging:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_debugging

Comment: OK, thanks for your patience. It is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS-Code you configure the build/run in the `tasks.json`, and the debug in the `launch.json` (all configuration files go under `${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/`).

You can set a keyboard shortcut for each task or for debug. For example my default build task is run with `Ctrl+Shift+B`and debug starts with `F5`. More info on how to set build/run/debug in VS-Code:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

And as shingo mentioned depending on the `externalConsole` flag you can control if a new terminal window pops up or not.

Comment: I have setted "externalConsole"=false, but it doesn't work.